# Как указать несколько типов данных, которые будет принимать хэндлер

Tags: python, aiogram

[image: Мой хэнлер]

Каким образом сделать, чтобы он принимал не только types.Message, но и Фото, Видео и ВидеоЗаметки(кружочки в телеграмме)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно менять тип `Message` так как это получает бот.
Из совета могу дать, не делать регистрацию хендлеров таким образом, так как это ломает ваше понимание кода.
Пример получения фото.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=types.ContentTypes.PHOTO)
async def photo_handler(msg: types.Message):
    photo = msg.photo[-1].file_id
```

Пример получения фото и/или видео.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[*types.ContentTypes.VIDEO, *types.ContentTypes.PHOTO])
async def photo_handler(msg: types.Message):
    video = msg.video.file_id if msg.video else None
    photo = msg.photo[-1].file_id if msg.photo else None
```